# Cannot hide index.php in nginx for socialengine rewrite

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, socialengine

I am new to nginx rewrite, but I am trying to run socialengine on nginx.  I have the following rewrite rules that seem to work everywhere except for domain.com/index.php or domain.com.  The rules seem to work for all of the other links (not in the /install/ path which I already know will require another set of rewrite rules).

What am I missing from my rules?

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  domain.com www.domain.com;
    root /home/user/public_html;
    index  index.php;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    # BLOCKS ACCESS TO . FILES (.svn, .htaccess, ...)
    location ~ /\. {
        deny  all;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @seRules;
    }

    location @seRules {
        rewrite /index\.php /index.php?rewrite=2;
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?rewrite=1;
    }

    location ~* \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass_request_body off;
        client_body_in_file_only clean;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_BODY_FILE $request_body_file;
    }

    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root   /home/user/public_html;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /home/user/public_html;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just include the following in the conf. This will hide the index.php too..

location ~ index.php {

```
root /home/user/public_html;

rewrite .* /index.php?rewrite=1 break;

fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/user/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /home/user/public_html;

fastcgi_pass_request_body off;
client_body_in_file_only clean;
fastcgi_param REQUEST_BODY_FILE $request_body_file;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
location /
{
if (!-e $request_filename) {rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?rewrite=1 last;}

# avoid redirect / -> /index.php
if ($request_uri = '/') {rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?rewrite=1 last;}
}
```